# symfony2 No redirect on restricted areas

Tags: php, symfony

I have my security file configured as follows:

```
security:
...
            pattern:    ^/[members|admin]
            form_login:
                check_path: /members/auth
                login_path: /public/login
                failure_forward: false
                failure_path: null
            logout:
                path:   /public/logout
                target: /
```

Currently if I access the members url without authenticating it redirects me to `/public/login` but I dont want it to redirect. I'm mainly responding with json on my controllers so I just want to show a warning on the restricted url such as `{"error": "Access denied"}`. If I take out the `login_path: /public/login` code it redirects to a default url /login. How do I do to stop it from redirecting?

Comment: I want to do the same thing. Somehow, I don't quite get Symfony... Is it such an unusual request do write AJAX controllers **with** authentication?

Answer (score 9):

You need to create a Listener and then trigger your response. My solution is based on - https://gist.github.com/xanf/1015146

Listener Code --

```
namespace Your\NameSpace\Bundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class AjaxAuthenticationListener
{

/**
 * Handles security related exceptions.
 *
 * @param GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event An GetResponseForExceptionEvent instance
 */
public function onCoreException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getException();
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException || $exception instanceof AccessDeniedException || $exception instanceof AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException) {
            $responseData = array('status' => 401, 'msg' => 'User Not Authenticated');
            $response = new JsonResponse();
            $response->setData($responseData);
            $response->setStatusCode($responseData['status']);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
}
```

You need to create a service for the listener --

```
e_ent_int_baems.ajaxauthlistener:
    class: Your\NameSpace\Bundle\Listener\AjaxAuthenticationListener
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onCoreException, priority: 1000 }
```

Comment: Allow me to add for future readers: - Take a look at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException() which is the default symfony implementation-

Comment: в 
" || $exception instanceof AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException"
нет необходимости, ибо оно наследует "AuthenticationException"

Answer (score 6):

You can do like I did:
in security.yml

```
firewalls:
        administrators:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path:  _security_check
                login_path:  _security_login
            logout: true
            security: true
            anonymous: true
            access_denied_url: access_denied
```

in routing.yml

```
access_denied:
    path: /error403
    defaults :
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: 'DpUserBundle:Static:error403.html.twig'
```

simply add to firewall section *access_denied_url* param

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/security.html) for the full `security.yml` configuration reference. Also, [this is an even better reference](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/form_login.html) with explanations of each key.

I'd suggest creating your own listener class to handle returning JSON when a User needs to login. Example: https://gist.github.com/1015146

Comment: those links you posted are not working, please update them